# how to find an object in powershell array?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm trying to work with arrays for the first time in Powershell (v3) so my vocabulary and upstanding needs a bit of assistance.

I would like to know what code would allow me to say: if my 'subnet' value is "1921683", what is my 'laptop' value? (I would of course expect the answer LT3)

I'm just importing the array (I think this is an array), via a csv file.

```
subnet,ou,laptop,desktop
1921681,MyOU1,LT1,DT1
1921682,MyOU2,LT2,DT2
1921683,MyOU3,LT3,DT3
1921684,MyOU4,LT4,DT4
1921685,MyOU5,LT5,DT5
1921686,MyOU6,LT6,DT6
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use convertfrom-csv to transform your csv to object then user select cmdlet :

```
PS>$c=get-content myfile.csv |ConvertFrom-Csv

subnet                  ou                      laptop                  desktop
------                  --                      ------                  -------
1921681                 MyOU1                   LT1                     DT1
1921682                 MyOU2                   LT2                     DT2
1921683                 MyOU3                   LT3                     DT3
1921684                 MyOU4                   LT4                     DT4
1921685                 MyOU5                   LT5                     DT5
1921686                 MyOU6                   LT6                     DT6



PS>$c |ConvertFrom-Csv |where subnet -eq 1921683 |select laptop

laptop
------
LT3
```

Comment: thank you for your pointer.  In my experiments I had been over complicating it, the closest I got to your example was  `$csv |where $csv.folder -eq 1921683 |select $csv.laptop`

Now I see I was over complicating things!  BTW I also tried it without the `|ConvertFrom-Csv` and that also worked